# Why does my notification bar get stuck on Galaxy S?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, notification-bar

The notification bar on my Samsung Galaxy S with Froyo has a nasty habit of getting stuck.  When this happens and I try to pull it down, the (I don't know what to call it) "dragging bar" appears, but I'm unable to pull it down.

I can access the notifications bar by going to the home screen, tapping the left button and tapping "notifications", but I can't access it any other way.

Is there a way to keep this from happening?

Is there any way to unstick it, other than restarting the phone?

This is the screen before I try to pull down the bar:
[image: Before trying to pull down the bar]

This is the screen after, with the notification bar stuck:
[image: notification bar is stuck]

(I actually took the screenshots in opposite order, which is why the clock is out of order in the two pictures).

Comment: I'd guessed the order they were taken by the clock! Slightly more on-topic, I haven't seen this with mine. Does it unstick it if you swap from the Home screen to the Applications screen, or if you start a full screen app (like a game) and then close it?

Comment: @GAThrawn: I thought so, I just didn't want to leave the impression that I was pasting unrelated screenshots because of the discrepancy.

Comment: Does it happen regardless of what home launcher you use?  Not sure if that'd make a difference...

Comment: I haven't tried any others. what good ones are there?

Comment: ADW.Launcher and LauncherPro seems to be the most popular

Comment: What Galaxy S model and what ROM?

Comment: Mine is doing the same also!! Very annoying! Searching for an answer and came across your thread, would love to know if anyone finds a solution. P.S. this has only started to happen since I downloaded some alarm clock apps, could this be related to the problem?

Comment: @Katie Yes, that could be the problem.  Any time you change something and something else changes, there could be a relationship.  Try uninstalling them and seeing what happens.

Comment: @Matthew: the model is `GT-I9000`. The firmware version is 2.2, the baseline is `I900JIJPS`, the core is `2.6.32.9 release@SEWA_ANRD_SRV2#1` and the build is `FROYO.JIJP7`

Comment: I've had this too, 2.2 firmware. Seems like something that 'triggers' a notification is stuck in a loop or something. I hope anybody knows a solution. Rebooting seems to work most of the time.

Comment: Now that you pointed it out, I just realized that this happens to mine as well from time to time. However, in my case (Samsung Spica - Samdroid Mod), a simple swipe to pull the bar down and up again would return it to normal.

Comment: A lot of the theories on this seem to be to do with CPU load and RAM usage. Is Samsung's 2.2.1 update available to your network yet? That has a lot of performance fixes in it and really makes a noticeable difference to the performance of the phone, I haven't had one odd pause or lock up since the update came out a couple of months ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your phone to Gingerbread and this problem will go away. I upgraded my Galaxy S to 2.3.3 and haven't ever since seen this problem, which still happened with 2.2.1 Froyo.

Comment: This actually solved the problem for me

Answer (score 4):

I HAVE FOUND A WORKAROUND!!!

First some details. This happens on the Galaxy S when you try to open the notification bar during high load. A reboot will reset it. But if you don't want to reboot:

Do this QUICKLY: Tap the notification bar, just before releasing it tap on the bottom half of the screen, release the finger from notification bar, release the finger from the bottom half of the screen.

This will trigger the notification bar to FULLY OPEN ITSELF!

Comment: It works, but requires some practice if you are 30+ years old. :-) BTW: This is really just a WORKAROUND, you still have to reset the phone.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is your problem or not, but I occasionally get this on my Droid X. For me, it seems that it's stuck if I try to slide down from the notification bar and nothing happens. However, if I start sliding down from the "pull-down bar", then it will move with my finger (i.e. starting on top of the "pull-down bar" rather than on the notification bar).

Another possibility is that your touchscreen could have some "dead areas" that cause this. Can you reproduce this in landscape mode as well or is it only in portrait mode? Perhaps an app to test all touchscreen areas might help identify whether or not this could be the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Galaxy S Captivate, and do see this occasionally. It only happens for me if I try to pull the notifications down while the phone is very busy doing something else, like installing/updating an app.

It goes away for me by simply just pushing it back to the top then pulling down again.

Answer (score 0):

I have this very problem, occasionally it'll make it half way down before sticking, and it's driving me nuts.

Someone pointed out it's most likely to do with RAM usage, clearing of which does seem to help for a period of time but isn't a permanent fix. I've tried changing launchers (from Zeam back to Touchwiz to LauncherPro) and applying a lagfix, both of which seemed to work, again for a time, but it has since come back. I've uninstalled my newest applications and haven't nailed down an exact culprit but there must be something hiding in there as this is a relatively recent occurence.